# how to override foundation small, medium and large breakpoint values?

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I am having a drupal theme child using foundation from a parent theme.
The standard breakpoints that are applying when using foundation classes and attributes are not precisely adapted to my site.
how to override foundation small, medium and large breakpoint values ?

Comment: You can do this only in the scss version.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you look in assets/scss/_settings.scss
About 108 lines down you get the $breakpoints: variable.
You can play with the values to until you get the required result. Make note of the original values to fall back on.